# Remove footer tags from CKEditor

Tags: php, html, ckeditor

I am using `CKEditor` in my website and here I want to remove footer tags. How can I do it? I am using `CKEditor` to add some useful content. It is working fine but I don’t want to show the footer tags. It shows `p` and `div` tags. How can I remove footer `p` and `div` tags from `CKEditor`?

Comment: Is this a problem with CKEditor, or with PHP? Can you share more details, like the code involved and your attempts to resolve the problem?

Answer (score 2):

It depends what the footer is displaying.
[This old thread](https://ckeditor.com/old/forums/CKEditor-3.x/remove-footer) suggests:

> Add this code in your config.js file :
>
> ```
> config.removePlugins = 'elementspath';
> config.resize_enabled = false;
> ```

This is part of the [basic configuration of CKEditor](https://ckeditor.com/docs/ckeditor4/latest/guide/dev_howtos_basic_configuration.html)

> If you, however, want to disable some functionality that comes from a CKEditor plugin and is still in your build, you can use the `removePlugins` setting to prevent the plugin from loading.
>
> ```
> // Remove one plugin.
> config.removePlugins = 'elementspath';
>
> // Remove multiple plugins.
> config.removePlugins = 'elementspath,save,font';
> ```

Answer (score 1):

**I was using ckeditor 5 classic version.**

1. Inspect element [Inspect screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Bo1nI.png) find the url like in my case "https://ckeditor.com/?utm_source=ckeditor&utm_medium=referral&utm_campaign=701Dn000000hVgmIAE_powered_by_ckeditor_logo"
2. Then download the ckeditor js file from CDN or somthing.
3. Format the file from any formatter online to better understand what to remove.
4. Now search in the URL we got in step1 in formatted js file.
5. Remove the whole class that contains this url (all other contents also can be seeen in the class)

In my case i removed the below mentioned class with the code :

```
  class fm extends Hi {
     constructor(t, e) {
        super(t);
        const n = new mr,
           o = this.bindTemplate;
        n.set({
           content: '<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="53" height="10" viewBox="0 0 53 10"><path fill="#1C2331" d="M31.724 1.492a15.139 15.139 0 0 0 .045 1.16 2.434 2.434 0 0 0-.687-.34 3.68 3.68 0 0 0-1.103-.166 2.332 2.332 0 0 0-1.14.255 1.549 1.549 0 0 0-.686.87c-.15.41-.225.98-.225 1.712 0 .939.148 1.659.444 2.161.297.503.792.754 1.487.754.452.015.9-.094 1.294-.316.296-.174.557-.4.771-.669l.14.852h1.282V.007h-1.623v1.485ZM31 6.496a1.77 1.77 0 0 1-.494.061.964.964 0 0 1-.521-.127.758.758 0 0 1-.296-.466 3.984 3.984 0 0 1-.093-.992 4.208 4.208 0 0 1 .098-1.052.753.753 0 0 1 .307-.477 1.08 1.08 0 0 1 .55-.122c.233-.004.466.026.69.089l.483.144v2.553c-.11.076-.213.143-.307.2a1.73 1.73 0 0 1-.417.189ZM35.68 0l-.702.004c-.322.002-.482.168-.48.497l.004.581c.002.33.164.493.486.49l.702-.004c.322-.002.481-.167.48-.496L36.165.49c-.002-.33-.164-.493-.486-.491ZM36.145 2.313l-1.612.01.034 5.482 1.613-.01-.035-5.482ZM39.623.79 37.989.8 38 2.306l-.946.056.006 1.009.949-.006.024 2.983c.003.476.143.844.419 1.106.275.26.658.39 1.148.387.132 0 .293-.01.483-.03.19-.02.38-.046.57-.08.163-.028.324-.068.482-.119l-.183-1.095-.702.004a.664.664 0 0 1-.456-.123.553.553 0 0 1-.14-.422l-.016-2.621 1.513-.01-.006-1.064-1.514.01-.01-1.503ZM46.226 2.388c-.41-.184-.956-.274-1.636-.27-.673.004-1.215.101-1.627.29-.402.179-.72.505-.888.91-.18.419-.268.979-.264 1.68.004.688.1 1.24.285 1.655.172.404.495.724.9.894.414.18.957.268 1.63.264.68-.004 1.224-.099 1.632-.284.4-.176.714-.501.878-.905.176-.418.263-.971.258-1.658-.004-.702-.097-1.261-.28-1.677a1.696 1.696 0 0 0-.888-.9Zm-.613 3.607a.77.77 0 0 1-.337.501 1.649 1.649 0 0 1-1.317.009.776.776 0 0 1-.343-.497 4.066 4.066 0 0 1-.105-1.02 4.136 4.136 0 0 1 .092-1.03.786.786 0 0 1 .337-.507 1.59 1.59 0 0 1 1.316-.008.79.79 0 0 1 .344.502c.078.337.113.683.105 1.03.012.343-.019.685-.092 1.02ZM52.114 2.07a2.67 2.67 0 0 0-1.128.278c-.39.191-.752.437-1.072.73l-.157-.846-1.273.008.036 5.572 1.623-.01-.024-3.78c.35-.124.646-.22.887-.286.26-.075.53-.114.8-.118l.45-.003.144-1.546-.286.001ZM22.083 7.426l-1.576-2.532a2.137 2.137 0 0 0-.172-.253 1.95 1.95 0 0 0-.304-.29.138.138 0 0 1 .042-.04 1.7 1.7 0 0 0 .328-.374l1.75-2.71c.01-.015.025-.028.024-.048-.01-.01-.021-.007-.031-.007L20.49 1.17a.078.078 0 0 0-.075.045l-.868 1.384c-.23.366-.46.732-.688 1.099a.108.108 0 0 1-.112.06c-.098-.005-.196-.001-.294-.002-.018 0-.038.006-.055-.007.002-.02.002-.039.005-.058a4.6 4.6 0 0 0 .046-.701V1.203c0-.02-.009-.032-.03-.03h-.033L16.93 1.17c-.084 0-.073-.01-.073.076v6.491c-.001.018.006.028.025.027h1.494c.083 0 .072.007.072-.071v-2.19c0-.055-.003-.11-.004-.166a3.366 3.366 0 0 0-.05-.417h.06c.104 0 .209.002.313-.002a.082.082 0 0 1 .084.05c.535.913 1.07 1.824 1.607 2.736a.104.104 0 0 0 .103.062c.554-.003 1.107-.002 1.66-.002l.069-.003-.019-.032-.188-.304ZM27.112 6.555c-.005-.08-.004-.08-.082-.08h-2.414c-.053 0-.106-.003-.159-.011a.279.279 0 0 1-.246-.209.558.558 0 0 1-.022-.15c0-.382 0-.762-.002-1.143 0-.032.007-.049.042-.044h2.504c.029.003.037-.012.034-.038V3.814c0-.089.013-.078-.076-.078h-2.44c-.07 0-.062.003-.062-.06v-.837c0-.047.004-.093.013-.14a.283.283 0 0 1 .241-.246.717.717 0 0 1 .146-.011h2.484c.024.002.035-.009.036-.033l.003-.038.03-.496c.01-.183.024-.365.034-.548.005-.085.003-.087-.082-.094-.218-.018-.437-.038-.655-.05a17.845 17.845 0 0 0-.657-.026 72.994 72.994 0 0 0-1.756-.016 1.7 1.7 0 0 0-.471.064 1.286 1.286 0 0 0-.817.655c-.099.196-.149.413-.145.633v3.875c0 .072.003.144.011.216a1.27 1.27 0 0 0 .711 1.029c.228.113.48.167.734.158.757-.005 1.515.002 2.272-.042.274-.016.548-.034.82-.053.03-.002.043-.008.04-.041-.008-.104-.012-.208-.019-.312a69.964 69.964 0 0 1-.05-.768ZM16.14 7.415l-.127-1.075c-.004-.03-.014-.04-.044-.037a13.125 13.125 0 0 1-.998.073c-.336.01-.672.02-1.008.016-.116-.001-.233-.014-.347-.039a.746.746 0 0 1-.45-.262c-.075-.1-.132-.211-.167-.33a3.324 3.324 0 0 1-.126-.773 9.113 9.113 0 0 1-.015-.749c0-.285.022-.57.065-.852.023-.158.066-.312.127-.46a.728.728 0 0 1 .518-.443 1.64 1.64 0 0 1 .397-.048c.628-.001 1.255.003 1.882.05.022.001.033-.006.036-.026l.003-.031.06-.55c.019-.177.036-.355.057-.532.004-.034-.005-.046-.04-.056a5.595 5.595 0 0 0-1.213-.21 10.783 10.783 0 0 0-.708-.02c-.24-.003-.48.01-.719.041a3.477 3.477 0 0 0-.625.14 1.912 1.912 0 0 0-.807.497c-.185.2-.33.433-.424.688a4.311 4.311 0 0 0-.24 1.096c-.031.286-.045.572-.042.86-.006.43.024.86.091 1.286.04.25.104.497.193.734.098.279.26.53.473.734.214.205.473.358.756.446.344.11.702.17 1.063.177a8.505 8.505 0 0 0 1.578-.083 6.11 6.11 0 0 0 .766-.18c.03-.008.047-.023.037-.057a.157.157 0 0 1-.003-.025Z"/><path fill="#AFE229" d="M6.016 6.69a1.592 1.592 0 0 0-.614.21c-.23.132-.422.32-.56.546-.044.072-.287.539-.287.539l-.836 1.528.009.006c.038.025.08.046.123.063.127.046.26.07.395.073.505.023 1.011-.007 1.517-.003.29.009.58.002.869-.022a.886.886 0 0 0 .395-.116.962.962 0 0 0 .312-.286c.056-.083.114-.163.164-.249.24-.408.48-.816.718-1.226.075-.128.148-.257.222-.386l.112-.192a1.07 1.07 0 0 0 .153-.518l-1.304.023s-1.258-.005-1.388.01Z"/><path fill="#771BFF" d="m2.848 9.044.76-1.39.184-.352c-.124-.067-.245-.14-.367-.21-.346-.204-.706-.384-1.045-.6a.984.984 0 0 1-.244-.207c-.108-.134-.136-.294-.144-.46-.021-.409-.002-.818-.009-1.227-.003-.195 0-.39.003-.585.004-.322.153-.553.427-.713l.833-.488c.22-.13.44-.257.662-.385.05-.029.105-.052.158-.077.272-.128.519-.047.76.085l.044.028c.123.06.242.125.358.196.318.178.635.357.952.537.095.056.187.117.275.184.194.144.254.35.266.578.016.284.007.569.006.853-.001.28.004.558 0 .838.592-.003 1.259 0 1.259 0l.723-.013c-.003-.292-.007-.584-.007-.876 0-.524.015-1.048-.016-1.571-.024-.42-.135-.8-.492-1.067a5.02 5.02 0 0 0-.506-.339A400.52 400.52 0 0 0 5.94.787C5.722.664 5.513.524 5.282.423 5.255.406 5.228.388 5.2.373 4.758.126 4.305-.026 3.807.21c-.097.046-.197.087-.29.14A699.896 699.896 0 0 0 .783 1.948c-.501.294-.773.717-.778 1.31-.004.36-.009.718-.001 1.077.016.754-.017 1.508.024 2.261.016.304.07.6.269.848.127.15.279.28.448.382.622.4 1.283.734 1.92 1.11l.183.109Z"/></svg>\n',
           isColorInherited: !1
        }), n.extendTemplate({
           attributes: {
              style: {
                 width: "53px",
                 height: "10px"
              }
           }
        }), this.setTemplate({
           tag: "div",
           attributes: {
              class: ["ck", "ck-powered-by"],
              "aria-hidden": !0
           },
           children: [{
              tag: "a",
              attributes: {
                 href: "https://ckeditor.com/?utm_source=ckeditor&utm_medium=referral&utm_campaign=701Dn000000hVgmIAE_powered_by_ckeditor_logo",
                 target: "_blank",
                 tabindex: "-1"
              },
              children: [...e ? [{
                 tag: "span",
                 attributes: {
                    class: ["ck", "ck-powered-by__label"]
                 },
                 children: [e]
              }] : [], n],
              on: {
                 dragstart: o.to((t => t.preventDefault()))
              }
           }]
        })
     }
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to add the below line in your config.js file:

`config.removePlugins = 'elementspath';`

Comment: What does it do? Also.. did you notice that this is also mentioned in the accepted Answer?

Comment: it removes body, p tags text from the Ckeditor's Footer

Comment: You should add that to your Answer.